# Hypercube point picking - unsolved?

Tags: random

[MathWorld says](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypercubePointPicking.html) that picking a random point in a unit $n$-cube is an unsolved problem. Why? Isn't it enough to pick $n$ random numbers uniformly distributed in $[0, 1]$?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64028/6179).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't say anything like that. It says that there is no known *closed-form expression* for the *expected distance* from a random point to a particular vertex of an $n$-cube.

Comment: Ah. So that's why they put it in the "Unsolved Problems" list?

Comment: Although one knows the asymptotics when the dimension $n\to\infty$, which is $\sqrt{n/3}$.